# Error using the substraction operator for two datetime64 empty series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two datetime64 columns:

```
In [119]: df.dtypes
Out[119]: 
beg    datetime64[ns]
end    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Sometimes, this dataframe can be empty. In this case, the substraction of `end` by `beg` fails using the minus operator but works using the `sub` method.

```
In [120]: df.end - df.beg
/Users/guillaumethomas/Documents/project/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:450: PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to Series not vectorized
  PerformanceWarning)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-cb2fc6857acf> in <module>()
----> 1 df.end - df.beg

/Users/guillaumethomas/Documents/project/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    607                     rvalues = com.take_1d(rvalues, ridx)
    608 
--> 609             arr = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    610 
    611             return left._constructor(wrap_results(arr), index=index,

/Users/guillaumethomas/Documents/project/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in <lambda>(x, y)
    452 
    453                 # pass thru on the na_op
--> 454                 self.na_op = lambda x, y: getattr(x,self.name)(y)
    455                 return lvalues, rvalues
    456 

TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

And this works

```
In [121]: df.end.sub(df.beg)
Out[121]: Series([], dtype: timedelta64[ns])
```

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html), `sub` is "Equivalent to `series - other`, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs." To my understanding, it does not explain the difference of behaviour. My questions are:

- Is it a bug?
- What are the differences between the `sub` method and the minus operator that are not explained in the documentation?
- Is it a good practice to always use `sub`, `add` etc instead of the operators? In my case, i'm prioritizing predictability over readibility.

My environment:

- python 3.4.3
- pandas 0.17.1

Answer (score 0):

It's answered in the documentation and in the sentence you copy-pasted:

> but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs

It supports empty dataframes and missing data where the minus operator doesn't.
With pandas and numpy, it's good practice to use member functions of the objects you're using.

Comment: Fair enough, i thought that "missing data" meant NaN values